# How do I send a string from dialogFragment to a Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to send an editText string from a dialogFragment popup to the activity screen behind it. I'm not sure how to do this in Kotlin since most resources online are in Java. I've tried to implement: [How to send data from dialog to my activity kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106534/how-to-send-data-from-dialog-to-my-activity-kotlin/56106862). However, I couldn't quite get it work so I'm not sure what method to use from here.

Here is the SelectAPScreen.kt (the activity I want the string to go to)

```
package com.wcsng.dlocapp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.imu_data.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader

class SelectAPScreen : AppCompatActivity(), OnButtonClick {


    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_apscreen)

        val directoryName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dir_field)
        val pingIP = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ip_field)
        val rpiIP = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.rpiField)
        val qtnIPs = {}

        val addQtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addQtn)
        addQtn.setOnClickListener {
            var dialog = AddQtnFragment()
            dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "Add Qtn Popup")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is the DialogFragment Code:

```
package com.wcsng.dlocapp

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.wcsng.dlocapp.R

class AddQtnFragment: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            // Get the layout inflater
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater

            val qtn_ip = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.qtn_ip)?.text.toString()


            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_qtn_popup, null))
                .setPositiveButton("Save", DialogInterface.OnClickListener{dialog, id ->
                    // TODO Return the qtn_ip to SelectAPScreen

                    // Close the dialog and return back to the parent activity
                    dialog.dismiss()
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener{dialog, id ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                })
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `getActivity()` or `requireActivity()` methods for obtaing managing `Activity`, then you may cast it to proper class, e.g. (requireActivity() as SelectAPScreen) and now you can call methods of it

```
(requireActivity() as SelectAPScreen).selectAPScreenMethod()
```

`selectAPScreenMethod()` is a custom method placed inside `SelectAPScreen` class